# Why start script with /usr/bin/env python

Tags: linux, scripting, python

I just downloaded a python script and noticed that the "shebang" line at the top looks like:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

instead of the familiar

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 6):

This is commonly used if the absolute path of the interpreter binary is not know or is assumed to be in different location from system to system.
For python one could have an installation in `/usr/local/` in addition to the ones installed by the distribution in `/usr/`. Without `env` in the shebang you would have to modify it to reflect your installation in `/url/local/`.

Comment: @Frank: if that answered your question, you should accept it (http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1033/how-can-i-accept-answers-to-my-questions)